# copying an XML node, modifying it & copying it

Tags: python, xml

hi have the following Code where i try to duplicate a certain XML node multiple times
and in each time insert a small modification according to a list.

the problem statement is: i always receive the last item on *list4xml*, copied all other copied nodes where i want to change on each indexing

```
temp= copy.deepcopy(root[1][0])  # i copy the node 
ind=0

for i in list4xml:
    temp[0][0][1].attrib['ExternalSource']=i
    root[1].insert(ind, temp)
    ind+=1
    if (ind>len(list4xml)):
        break
```

it seems that somehow modifying temp affect the root.
how to disconnect the two items.

my input xml looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Site SiteName="abcdefg" SiteType="128">
  <FileDescription VersionOfObject="3.0" SourceAppName="abcd" DataType="IPSequenceData" />
  <DataSetCollection>
    <DataSet Attempt="0" Quadrant="0" Frame="0">
      <ReportData>
        <ImageData>
          <DataFile FileTypeID="312" FileTypeName="Golden Image" ExternalSource="5.bmp" />
          <DataFile FileTypeID="313" FileTypeName="Scanned Image" ExternalSource="1.3_1.bmp" />
        </ImageData>
        <ParamValues>
          <ParamValue ParTypeID="8" ParID="7" ParName="Location Uncertainty" Value="20" />
        </ParamValues>
      </ReportData>
      <ResultInfo Result="True" BestMark="0.7781224" SecondMark="0">
        <SearchRegion X="0" Y="0" Width="640" Height="480" />
        <RequiredPoint X="320" Y="240" />
        <RoiCenter X="320" Y="240" />
        <ModelCenterOnTarget X="320" Y="230" />
      </ResultInfo>
      <GmpData ExternalSource="abcd_efg.xml" />
    </DataSet>
  </DataSetCollection>
</Site>
```

im trying to duplicate the entire ***DataSet*** Node with his childeren multiple times
and for each edit the attribute ***ExternalSource="1.3_1.bmp" ***

the result i get is that all the copied node contain the last item in
**list4xml** list, instead of different value per each node

Comment: Please edit your question, and add the following: (1) input XML, (2) desired output, (3) logic to apply.

Answer (score 0):

I Managed to solved by the following code
putting a **copy.deepcopy** inside the loop
& inserting the new node only after i modified the Node

```
ind=0
for i in list4xml:
    # root[1].append(temp)
    # root[1].copy.deepcopy(temp)
    temp = copy.deepcopy(root[1][0])
    temp[0][0][0].attrib['ExternalSource'] = list4xml[0]
    temp[0][0][1].attrib['ExternalSource']=i
    root[1].insert(ind, temp)
    ind+=1
    if (ind>len(list4xml)):
        break
```